# Why am I unable to combine xpath for finding first and last child with certain attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath

Right now I am trying to do an xpath statement that will find the first child with an attribute value of val=y and the last child with the same attribute val=y both at the same time. I am able to do one or the other but I can't do both. I have even looked at other similar posts and they don't seem to work in this instance. Here is what I have tried.

Tried this one but no matches.

```
child::*[@val='y'][1]/child::*[@val='y'][last()]
```

Tried this one and got a bunch of garbled text in my xml.

```
child::*[@val='y'][1] | child::*[@val='y'][last()]
```

Tried switching the conditions around and still nothing happened.

```
child::*[last()][@val='y']/child::*[1][@val='y']
```

So why can't I get the right match? Why doesn't similar solutions in other posts work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
child::*[@val='y'][position() = 1 or position() = last()]
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. Consider yourself checked.